# I can not pass data from c# server to GCM app

Tags: c#, android, google-cloud-messaging

So i'm trying to send some data from my c# server to my gcm android application. It works just fine(after whole day of work) but i can't figure out how to actualy send some data(and recieve it). On my c# side i have:

```
     using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "key=" + "key");
            var nameValues = new NameValueCollection
                     {
                         {"registration_id", "id"},
                         {"collapse_key", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()},
                         {"data.payload", "works!!!!!!"},
                         {"message", "YES it works!!!"}
                     };
            var resp = wc.UploadValues("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send",nameValues);
            var respMessage = Encoding.Default.GetString(resp);
            MessageBox.Show("Got respose from GCM: " + respMessage);
        }
```

and in my onmessage method on android application i have:

```
     protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Log.i("Registration", "Got a message!");
    Log.i("Registration", arg0.toString() + " " + arg1.toString());
    String score =  arg1.getExtras().getString("message");
    score=arg1.getExtras().getString("data.payload");
```

The problem is that my score String is always null :S

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is that POST fields called "data.Foo" are passed as intent extras called "Foo". To retrieve an extra called "payload", you need to pass "data.payload" and retrieve `arg1.getStringExtra("payload").

By the way, you're retrieving score twice - as "message" and as "data.payload". Neither is right.